# How to stop jQuery converting html entities into valid HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Weeding out a few issues with my site when I found this curious issue.

```
<img src=".." width="1200" height="1200" alt="&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;foo&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;" />
```

The CMS appears to have done it's jobs and converted `<script>alert('foo')</script>` into what you see above. I display the caption with the following code.

```
site.caption = {

    container : $('#caption'),

    set : function(str) {

        if (str && str.length) {
            this.container.html('<span>'+str+'</span>').show(); console.log(str);
        } else {
            this.container.hide();
        }

    }

};
```

The function is called like this.

```
site.caption.set($(nextSlideElement).find('img').attr('alt'));
```

When this line runs an alert box pop's up with the text 'foo'. When I do the following in the `site.caption.set` function it shows the valid html.

```
console.log(str);
```

I am using jQuery 1.8.3. Does anyone know why this is happening? How do I show the text `<script>alert('foo')</script>` without it being run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery isn't converting it, the browser is when it parses the HTML.

If you want to treat a string as text instead of HTML, then use `jQuery('foo').text(value)` instead of `jQuery('foo').html(value)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.container.html('<span>'+str+'</span>')
```

Never concatenate HTML strings. Let jQuery do it for you. Get into this habit and you won't run into this problem.

```
this.container.empty().append($('<span/>').text(str));
```